# Could not find coffee-script-source-1.1.3 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

Hi I'm doing Rails app and when I bundle install it returns an error:

`Could not find coffee-script-source-1.1.3 in any of the sources`

I know that **coffee-script-source-1.1.3** gem is **deprecated/yanked** but my other gems are having dependencies with this.

But this project is working with other machine and in heroku production.
How can I successfully bundle install this without changing my gemfile?
Thanks

Comment: It is OK to host your own gem source, and add that source to Gemfile?

Answer (score 13):

Run this:

```
bundle update --source coffee-script-source
```

If you get an error, like this:

```
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

Run this:

```
 gem install rmagick
```

I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

What it worked for me was to **update** the gem to **1.2.0**.

As it shows here https://rubygems.org/gems/coffee-script-source/versions
1.1.3 says that it's yanked.

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '~> 1.2.0'
```

And run

```
bundle update --source coffee-script-source
```