# Heroku could not find coffee-script-source 1.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, coffeescript

Hi I'm developing rails app that requires **coffee-script-source 1.1.3** I know that this gem is yanked so I downloaded this specific version and place it on my vendor/cache. I ran bundle install when testing it on **development** stage it's working fine But when pushing this project to Heroku I'm getting:

[image: heroku error]

How can I make it work? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find coffee-script-source-1.1.3 in any of the sources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063061/could-not-find-coffee-script-source-1-1-3-in-any-of-the-sources)

Comment: Hi Monk_Code I'm also the one who asked that. I solved that problem by adding coffee-script-source 1.1.3 gem to my vendor/cache. But now my problem now is I cannot push this project to Heroku.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem. Can you make a minor version jump to coffee-script-source-1.7.0? Running

```
bundle update --source coffee-script-source
```

will update just that gem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by downloading the yanked gem and uploaded it to a Github or you can also import the downloaded gem to your project and in your Gemfile reference it into your downloaded gem's location.